# Busca interna com HTML

Tags: html5

Boa noite pessoas! Estou criando um site de filmes e queria saber como faço um sistema de busca interna nele, tipo, já está tudo criado, o input e o button, agora só falta fazer funcionar! Eu quero que ao mesmo tempo em que digito na barra, ele sugira alguns títulos e ao clicar redirecione para uma página específica. Sou iniciante nisso tudo, sei pouco sobre programação no geral, e preciso de ajuda! Pensei em criar uma página em HTML com uma "lista" dos filmes, e essa lista seria usada nas sugestões. Obrigado :)

Comment: Bem-vindo, para obter uma resposta que resolva sua dúvida/problema,
 por favor leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Para isso você precisará de uma linguagem de programação. Dependendo da estrutura da sua aplicação essa linguagem deverá ser executada no lado do servidor auxiliada pelo JavaScript ou somente esta segunda. No geral, sua pergunta está ampla demais e não poderá ser respondida. Como estão armazenados os dados dos filmes? Está utilizando alguma linguagem no servidor? Qual? E banco de dados? Tem conhecimento de JavaScript?

Comment: Não tenho servidor ainda, o site está todo em html e css. cada filme é uma page, e para redirecionar uso um figure com ancora. Basicamente isso. Não tenho conhecimento em JS. E não tenho banco de dados

Comment: Com HTML puro você não vai conseguir fazer nada

Comment: E com JS, como ficaria uma base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente uma aplicação assim possui uma estrutura de banco de dados muito bem definida, com relações entre tabelas, se necessário e uma linguagem de programação no lado do servidor controlando tudo. Se sua aplicação não mostrou necessidade disso tudo, ok, mas tornar as coisas dinâmicas em um site de conteúdo estático é um trabalho árduo e nem sempre produz resultados satisfatórios. Dito isso, recomendo você a estudar uma linguagem de programação e banco de dados. A combinação PHP + MySQL se mostra bem receptiva para iniciantes.

Apenas com JavaScript é possível criar alguma coisa, mas como comentei, o resultado nem sempre é tão satisfatório. Dado que todo o seu site foi construído em arquivos estáticos, diretamente no HTML, acredito que a quantidade de conteúdo deve ser pequena - se não for, você deve aprender a linguagem de programação urgentemente. E como você deseja apenas fazer uma busca e redirecionamento, você pode armazenar os dados de todos os filmes em uma estrutura no JavaScript e utilizá-la nas buscas.

Vamos supor que existem 3 filmes, então poderia fazer algo como:

```
const movies = [
  {title: "Alice no País das Maravilhas", url: "alice.html"},
  {title: "Harry Potter e a Pedra Filosofal", url: "harry.html"},
  {title: "Karate Kid", url: "karate.html"}
];
```

Sempre que um novo filme for adicionado ao site, esta estrutura deverá ser atualizada manualmente. Assim, ao digitar algo no campo de busca, você poderia efetuar uma busca *fuzzy* nos títulos dos filmes retornando os títulos relacionados.

```js
const movies = [{
    title: "Alice no País das Maravilhas",
    url: "alice.html"
  },
  {
    title: "Harry Potter e a Pedra Filosofal",
    url: "harry.html"
  },
  {
    title: "Karate Kid",
    url: "karate.html"
  }
];

// Estes elementos servirão para a manipulação do DOM: elementos HTML
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const list = document.getElementById("movies");

// Aqui atribuímos uma função ao evento `keyup` do campo no HTML
// Isto é, sempre que uma tecla for pressionada, a função será executada:
title.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

  // Filtramos a lista de filmes com base no texto digitado:
  const matchs = movies.filter(value => {

    // Se o texto digitado for encontrado no título, retorna o registro:
    return value.title.indexOf(this.value) !== -1;

  });
   
  // Exibe no HTML a lista de filmes do resultado do filtro anterior:
  list.innerHTML = "";
  for (let movie of matchs) {
    list.innerHTML += "<li><a href='"+movie.url+"'>"+movie.title+"</a></li>";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Digite o título do filme">

<ul id="movies"></ul>
```

Perceba que ao começar a digitar um título no campo uma lista de sugestões com os links para cada filme é criada logo abaixo. Se este resultado já é satisfatório para você, já pode concluir que precisará estudar JavaScript.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Isso já está de bom tamanho, quero algo simples mesmo, e aos poucos irei estudando e aperfeiçoando. Mas agora fiquei em dúvida se foco no PHP + MySQL ou se aprendo o JS.

Comment: No final, ambos. Eles não são exclusivos. Depende se você quer atuar mais no lado do cliente, estudando JS, ou no lado do servidor, estudando PHP.

Comment: Certo! Muito Obrigado. Resolveu meu problema

Comment: Olá pessoal, gostei desse código e como seria se eu tivesse dois campos de busca, titulo e url por exemplo e gostaria de fazer a pesquisa que contenha os valores digitados, o usuário pode digitar um ou outro ou ambos.